# microdisplacement and render farms

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a large animation to render that I just can't do on my machine.
Does anybody know of a good render farm that supports micro-displacement in Blender's Experimental mode?

And/or is there a workaround that will give me the look I need without using micro-d?

Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!
I ended up emailing every Render Farm I could find. Render Street was the only one that got back to me with a 100% yes.
If I get any more positives, I'll add them to this thread, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/ seems to say that it is just made out of lots of volunteers' computers, and it is specifically for Blender, so I should think that would support it.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

GarageFarm will add any nightly builds or enable experimental features for you on request. FYI, Blender has 33% lower rates than other 3D software on the farm. Might be a deal-breaker for you https://garagefarm.net/pricing/.